# Oracle 9.2 - Order By Ignored If Order By Columns Not First

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-order-by, oracle9i

I'm new to Oracle SQL, and have recently discovered that my 'Order By' statement is ignored in P/L SQL scripts when creating temp tables if I don't put the order by columns at the front of the list of select columns.

i.e. This statement returns an unordered result set, my order by ignored (seems to actually be sorting by column A.ACCOUNT_ID - a numeric/integer unique ID)

```
SELECT
    A.ACCOUNT_ID,
    PRODUCT_CATEGORY,
    PRODUCT_NAME,
    PRICE,
    COST,
    QUANTITY
FROM
    TABLEA   A
    LEFT JOIN TABLEB   B ON A.ACCOUNT_ID = B.ACCOUNT_ID
ORDER BY
    PRODUCT_CATEGORY,
    PRODUCT_NAME
```

But this works fine, ordering the result set as intended and written

```
SELECT

    PRODUCT_CATEGORY,
    PRODUCT_NAME,
    A.ACCOUNT_ID,
    PRICE,
    COST,
    QUANTITY
FROM
    TABLEA   A
    LEFT JOIN TABLEB   B ON A.ACCOUNT_ID = B.ACCOUNT_ID
ORDER BY
    PRODUCT_CATEGORY,
    PRODUCT_NAME
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I remember something simmilar happening in SQL server (i.e. CTEs would warn 'order by ignored in common table expressions or something like that) - but in this case there is no CTE - the end statement example I have here comes at the end of a script which produces multiple temp tables, and builds a final temp table where I want the result set ordered.

I'd appreciate any wisdom you all have to share.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add sample data to your question to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: Please prepend each column with its table alias. It may be evident to you where each column comes from, but not for us.

Comment: "...when creating temp tables..." -- tables do not have inherent row ordering. The `ORDER BY` clause is useless there.

Comment: What do you mean by "produces many temp tables"?  Oracle temp tables are generally not created on the fly as in SQL Server, they're created once and populated in scripts-- Oracle doesn't have local temp tables.  Oracle 9.2 is also very (very) old and one of if not the first version of Oracle to support the LEFT JOIN syntax rather than using the old `(+)` operator.  There were occasional optimizer bugs in old versions of Oracle using the new style syntax when it was transformed to the old style syntax so you might try using the old syntax and applying patchsets if you're not on the latest.

Comment: Generally, the answer to the question *"why is my database doing this weird thing?" turns out to be your database is not doing that weird thing, but there is something happening which you have overlooked or mis-interpreted. This  definitely seems that sort of question and so requires **a reproducible test case**. Although if the effect is genuinely an artefact of running on Oracle 9i R2 then a test case will have little utility, because I suspect very few people still have access to such an old version of the RDBMS.

Comment: Incidentally the reference to *"a script which produces multiple temp tables"*, coupled with your prior exposure to SQL Server suggests you may be implementing bad practice. Oracle global temporary tables are very different from T-SQL temp tables, and shouldn't be created on the fly in a script. Indeed Oracle is very different from SQL Server, and the valid use cases for temporary tables are far less numerous in Oracle than MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

> builds a final temp table where I want the **result set ordered**

Standard Oracle table is a **heap-organized** table, that means rows are stored in no particular order.

So, the ordering is never guaranteed while returning the rows unless you explicitly use an ORDER BY clause while SELECTing the rows. You cannot control the ordering while storing the data in the table.

From Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16508/glossary.htm#CHDBJDCA):

```
heap-organized table

A table in which the data rows are stored in no particular order on disk. 
By default, CREATE TABLE creates a heap-organized table.
```